# Python - Kivy cascade training: How to obtain touch coordinates relative to image?

Tags: python, opencv, kivy

I'm trying to make a cascade training application in Python and Kivy in which you can easily load an image and zoom in and rotate the image using multitouch and indicate with double touch the objects that I want to cropped out the image to save them in a separate folder to use lateron for training a cascade classifier. The problem I'm currently face is that I only get the coordinates of the window, which I do not manage to convert to the coordinates of the image using to_parant etc. Any suggestion to solve this issue would be very welcome!

```
if touch.is_double_tap:
     user_textinput = self.ids['user_textinput'] # change the text in the box where the user can put in the file directory by the created image name 
     image = cv2.imread(user_textinput.text)
     x = int(touch.x)
     y = int(touch.y)
     w_double = 30
     h_double = 30

     crop_img = image[x-w_double/2:y-h_double/2, w_double:h_double] # Crop from x, y, w, h
     cv2.imwrite("positive.jpg", crop_img)

     cv2.rectangle(image,(x-w_double/2,y-h_double/2),(x+w_double/2,y+h_double/2),(255,255,255),3)              
     feedback_img_dir = 'product_pictures/feedback_' + str(time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))  + ".jpg"   # create name for image with a time stamp   
     cv2.imwrite(feedback_img_dir, image)
     print "feedback_img saved as " + feedback_img_dir

     user_textinput = self.ids['user_textinput'] # change the text in the box where the user can put in the file directory by the created image name 
     user_textinput.text = str(feedback_img_dir) 
else:
   return super(GUI, self).on_touch_down(touch) # assures that if noth double click or ... the other withgets can still be used
```

Answer (score 0):

To_parent (and friends) is only needed to change from one coordinate system into another, like, when e.g a RelativeLayout, or a ScrollView is used, save for that, your image's position is in the coordinate system it recieve the touch event in, and its position is relative to it, so you just have to substract it's position to the touch's position to get it relative.

```
X, Y = touch.x - image.x, touch.y - image.y
```

Alternatively, you could nest your Image in a RelativeLayout to directly get that transformation.

Comment: I can agree that if the image would be displayed with scale 1 this would work, but I currently display the image in a scatterview to enable double touch scaling and rotation and single touch translation. Any suggestions how to obtain the correct coordinates in this case?

Comment: Well, if you use a Scatter, it gets the touch at the correct position already, if you want to do a check in its coordinate system from another widget, then you do need the scatter.to_widget() method. However, i'm not sure cropping will work the way you intend this way, especially if rotation is involved, a more complete version of the code would help, so one can see how the Scatter and the code you gave are related. A better solution could be to use an FBO to render the current state of the scatter in the parent's coordinate system, and crop this one instead.